# Why is the sample standard deviation used in the z-test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, standard-error, standardization, z-test

The assumption of the z-test is that the population standard deviation $\sigma$ is known. With this in mind I tried to manually compute the p-value for a (one-tailed) z-test that the sample mean $\bar{X}$ is greater than 0, and compare it with the z-test p-value given by a popular stats toolbox.

Naively, I thought that if the population standard deviation $\sigma$ is known, I would use it to normalize my mean $\bar{X}$:

$$
z=\frac{\bar{X}}{\sigma/\sqrt{N}}
$$

However, the toolbox is not even asking for the population standard deviation $\sigma$. By testing, I found that it uses the sample standard deviation $\hat{\sigma}$.

Why is that? Is this the general logic of the z-test and if yes, why would we not make use of the known population standard deviation?

For reference, this is the toolbox z-test I tried: https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ztest.html#statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ztest

Comment: Ok, I see that this might have been a specific choice by the authors of statsmodels. In R  (e.g. https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BSDA/versions/1.2.1/topics/z.test ) I'm able to supply a population standard deviation.

Comment: Same with Matlab https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ztest.html, so I guess I posted this question a bit prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, population parameters are unknown so we have to estimate them.  If $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, and $\hat{s}$ the sample standard deviation, then the statistic

$$ \dfrac{\bar{x}}{\hat{s} / \sqrt{n}} $$

technically has t-distribution.  However, when $n$ is sufficiently large, the sampling distribution of this statistic is very close to a normal distribution. So close that using the normal in place of the student-t to compute p values leads to nominal differences.

Comment: Thanks! So would you say that the formally correct way would be to use the population standard deviation in my formula above? And if I don't know $\sigma$ anyway then just use a t-test? I found it weird that a popular toolbox wouldn't allow me to perform a formally correct z-test by supplying $\sigma$ & hence though I might have missed something.

Comment: It would be correct to do a t-test since you don't know $\sigma$ and have to estimate it, but if $n$ is large enough then the difference is very small between the two approaches.

Comment: As mentioned in my post I specifically assume that I know $\sigma$.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer, when the data are large then the use of a z as opposed to a t test can still lead to valid conclusions.  The authors of statsmodels know that pop parameters are rarely known in practice so it doesn't make sense to write a function for an applied stats library to specify the pop parameters.

Comment: Here is where I would disagree. One would just use a t-test in case of unknown $\sigma$ (which statsmodels also offers). If a toolbox is additionally providing a z-test, then it's strange that you can't compute formally correct z/p-values with the test.